# Why does the directory go before 2>&1 but after 2>/?

Tags: bash

I've been looking around for an answer yet I cannot find one. My question is the syntax of the above commands.

Why would I need to put the directory before one but after the other? 
example:

```
>~/Desktop/log 2>&1

2>~/Desktop/log
```

Because when I try

```
2>&1~/Desktop/log
```

or

```
2>&1>~/Desktop/log
```

They do not work, which I am OK with. That's fine. I just want to know why the syntax seemingly contradicts itself.

Comment: I think this question should be asked in http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Redirection can go before or after the command it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: `>&2 echo foo`, for example, will still write to standard error.

Comment: What do you feel is contradictory here exactly? Also that last example should work. Is it not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is one of spacing and what the bits of the line mean.

`>~/Desktop/log 2>&1` means redirect standard output `>` to `~/Desktop/log` and then redirect standard error `2>` to the standard output (file descriptor 1, `&1`).

Similarly with `2>~/Desktop/log` which is redirect standard error `2>` to `~/Desktop/log`.

That being said `2>&1~/Desktop/log` is confused (ambiguous) because it is unclear what you meant for that to be doing.

You also cannot redirect output to a directory as that isn't a valid target for writing output.

The order of redirections on a line matters in that they occur in a left-to-right manner. So `>file 2>&1` redirects both standard output and standard error to the file but `2>&1 >file` redirects standard error to where standard output is and *then* redirects standard output somewhere else (leaving standard error going to the old location).

Answer (score 2):

When I try:

```
: 2>&1/dev/null
```

I get an 'ambiguous redirect' error (from Bash 4.3.28 - with some custom patches).

If I used:

```
: 2>&1 /dev/null
```

with a space, then the `/dev/null` is simply an argument to the `:` command (which is a no-op — it is convenient for testing, that's all).  The I/O redirection sends standard error to standard output for the duration of the `:` command.

With:

```
: 2>&1>/dev/null
```

the shell doesn't whinge.  It treats `2>&1` as one redirection, `>/dev/null` as another and gets on with life.

The notations:

```
: 2>/dev/null
: 2> /dev/null
```

both specify that standard error should go to `/dev/null`.

Main moral of the story: keep I/O redirections separate from each other.  Spaces are cheap and should be used to avoid ambiguity and to make it easier for other people (including yourself in six months time!) to read and understand.

Comment: Good point about `2>&1>/dev/null` not complaining. I didn't test it I just assumed the OP was correct.